# AlpineJS select2 component inside another scope throws error

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have the following AlpineJS component inside a blade file:

select.blade.php

```
<div wire:ignore>

<div
    x-data="{value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model'))}"
    x-init="$nextTick(() => {
            select2 = $($refs.select).select2();
            select2.on('select2:select', (event) => {value = event.target.value});
            })">

    <select x-ref="select"
            x-bind:value="value"
        {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}>

        {{$slot}}

    </select>

</div>

</div>
```

Then I put it inside a livewire component, bounding with wire:model

```
<div>
  <x-backoffice.forms.select wire:model="perPage">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
  </x-backoffice.forms.select>
</div>
```

This works fine having several select2 components on the page, but if I wrap the component on another x-data scope, I get the following error from JQuery:

[image]

I need to wrap it because I have to put the select2 inside a modal dialog, and I control the visibility with alpine. The component works fine, but I prefer to avoid the message and know why this is happening.

The JQuery version is 3.5.1 (tried with 2.2.4 too) and select2 is 4.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason the error disappear if I send the selector ID instead of $ref.

Changed

```
$($refs.select).select2();
```

with

```
$('#id').select2();
```

Then I pass the ID via props.